# Sort array values after search php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hi for some reasons When **I did a search with a form(POST Method)** I got an array which look like this below:

```
      Array(
            [0] =>Array ( [0] => 2008 [1] => Name1 [2] => Surname1 )
            [1] =>Array ( [0] => 2009 [1] => Name2 [2] => Surname2 ) 
            [2] =>Array ( [0] => 2010 [1] => Name3 [2] => Surname3 )
           )
```

How can I sort this array without executing any other query and using $_GET parameter or another for getting an array which look like this:

```
       Array(
            [0] =>Array ( [0] => 2010 [1] => Name3 [2] => Surname3 )
            [1] =>Array ( [0] => 2009 [1] => Name2 [2] => Surname2 ) 
            [2] =>Array ( [0] => 2008 [1] => Name1 [2] => Surname1 )
           )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `array_reverse()` function.

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php